# Епископ-женщина одним словом

Tags: словообразование

Проще, более по-русски, звучит "епископша", но традиция (диаконисса, архимандритисса) склоняет к написанию "еспискописса".

И, кстати, в ту же, церковную, тему:

Диаконисса или дьяконисса? На что опираться при выборе написания?

Comment: В "гугл-книгах" достаточно часто встречается _епископиня_; в википедии есть _дьяконица_.

Comment: Врач Иванова - епископ Ге́рда Е́ва Сеси́лия Бру́нне.  Такие сочетания звучат нормально. Может, поэтому новое слово никак не придумывается?

Comment: Только у католиков такие послабления происходят. Наше же духовенство — всё мужеского полу, и женщины в храме, где мужья служат, или помогают службе, именуются матушками. Это «проще, и более по-русски».

Comment: Об абсурдности этой «церковной темы» и этого вопроса: Мария Магдалина, Фекла – женщины, которые по своим дарованиям оказались на одном уровне с апостолами, занимались тем же – проповедью христианства. Но нигде и никогда уровень их церковного почитания не соединялся с дарованием им священства. Божия Матерь, почитаемая выше Ангелов, не была священником. Ни в Писании, ни в святоотеческой литературе нет ни одного факта, подтверждающего возможность женского священства». https://azbyka.ru/pochemu-tolko-muzhchiny